# How can I make my database connection (Oracle) with NODEJS(ORM)?

Tags: node.js, typescript, oracle, typeorm, oracle-autonomous-db

I want to connect my Oracle Cloud database which is known as standalone database and already managed to make the connection with NODEJS ([oracle documentation](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/quickstartnodejs.html)), but I still can not implement with ORM and is with which I have problems I'm using [Typeorm.io](https://typeorm.io/#/) that says it is compatible with Oracle, but I have no idea how to do it. I hope you can help me:

```
They are connection data = {censorship}
```

This is my file `db.ts` trying to use `Typeorm.io`

```js
import {
  createConnection
} from "typeorm";


createConnection({
  type: "oracle",
  username: "admin",
  password: "{censorship}",
  database: "DB{censorship}_high",
  synchronize: true,
  logging: false
}).then(connection => {
  console.log('connect database')
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

This is my connection file that works correctly for me `db.js`

```js
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
let dbConfig = require('./dbconfig');

oracledb.initOracleClient({
  libDir: 'D:\\MaterialSkywork\\Oracle\\instantclient_21_3'
});


console.log(dbConfig)

async function Open(sql, binds, autoCommit) {
  let cnn = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);
  let result = await cnn.execute(sql, binds, {
    autoCommit
  });
  cnn.release();
  return result;
}

exports.Open = Open;
```

This was my test to the autonome database `index.js`

```js
const BD = require('./db.js');

async function start() {

  sql = "select * from elopez.orders";


  let result = await BD.Open(sql, [], false);
  Orders = [];

  result.rows.map(order => {
    let userSchema = {
      "order": order[0],
      "order_status": order[3],
    }

    Orders.push(userSchema);
  })

  console.log(Orders);
}

start()
```

[image]

Or if you can't how can I migrate my `db.js` file to `db.ts`, I tried, however I had many problems passing Typescript and open to your opinions to improve my code and use good practices to avoid any vulnerability, thanks.

Comment: What's the error?  From looking at `node_modules/typeorm/driver/oracle/OracleDriver.js` you might need to use `connectString: "DB{censorship}_high",` instead of using `database`.  On Windows you might find it easier to add the Instant Client directory to the PATH environment variable instead of calling `initOracleClient()` (macOS users can add a sym link as shown in the oracledb doc).  If you are having problems with wallets, then make sure you use the same configuration as your plain application or see https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/how-to-connect-to-oracle-autonomous-cloud-databases

Answer (score 0):

To migrate db.js to db.ts first, you'll need to make sure you have the OracleDB TypeScript declarations installed:

```
npm install @types/oracledb --save-dev
```

Now, let's migrate your db.js file to db.ts:

```
import oracledb, { Connection } from 'oracledb';

const dbConfig: oracledb.ConnectionAttributes = {
  user: 'admin',
  password: '{censorship}',
  connectString: 'DB{censorship}_high',
};

async function Open(sql: string, binds: any[], autoCommit: boolean): Promise<oracledb.Result<any>> {
  let connection: Connection;
  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);
    const result = await connection.execute(sql, binds, { autoCommit });
    return result;
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      connection.close();
    }
  }
}

export { Open };
```

Improvements and Good Practices:

1. Using async/await and Promises: Using async/await and Promises is a
   good practice for handling asynchronous operations like database
   connections and queries.
2. Properly Handling Connection Release: I've added a finally block to
   ensure the database connection is properly released, even in case of
   exceptions.
3. Type Annotations: TypeScript's static typing helps catch potential
   errors during development. I've added type annotations where
   necessary.
4. Importing oracledb: Import oracledb and Connection from the module
   to get type information for better type checking.
5. Configuring Connection: The connection configuration object
   (dbConfig) is now defined with proper typing.
6. Using ES6 export: I've switched to using ES6 export instead of
   module.exports. This aligns with modern JavaScript practices and
   TypeScript.
7. File Naming Conventions: Typically, TypeScript files are named with
   a .ts extension.

Comment: hey, just checking- did you get this from chatgpt? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541